# Flutter: jsonEncode for a List

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

I am trying to jsonEncode a list in Flutter.

```
List<String> _list = ["name1", "name2"]
```

Things I tried:

```
jsonEncode(_list);
jsonEncode(_list.map((e) => e.toString()).toList());
```

This gives me a Json String however the data I get is:

```
"[\"name1\",\"name2\"]"
```

I want to send the data so that it shows:

```
{
  0: "name1",
  1: "name2"
}
```

PS: I am using Realtime Firebase Database for backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have an Integer as a key in a valid Json Object. This is possible in JS, but not in the Json spec.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. However this is giving me an error: "Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'ListMapView<String>'"

Comment: Oh I thought its an actual Map, give me a minute or so

Comment: Ok I have edited it, this should at least give some more information

Comment: Omg, im dumb. You cant have an Integer as a key in json. Only strings are legal. JS allows ints, json doesn't